# Jmeter Cookie manager impact of AWS sticky sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, jmeter, autoscaling, cookiemanager

I have created a Jmeter script to check the performance of a site. The website is hosted in AWS with elastic scaling and with sticky sessions. Basically the AWS load balancer will assign a session cookie to each user so the load balancer can direct the user to the correct instance.

[image]
[source](https://www.imperva.com/learn/availability/sticky-session-persistence-and-cookies/)

My problem is, as I'm using a cookie manager and clearing all the cookies with each iteration. Does it clear these assigned cookies too? I suspect this because the script error rate is lower when we execute the script on a single AWS instance than in auto-scaling  ( multiple instances )

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the JMeter script. It's with the AWS ELB in a elastic server config. We had configured a Alarm to remove the instance from load balancer, so even with the stickey sessions enabled  when the instance is removed it generated the error.
After moving the session managemet to a Elasticache - Redid based solution, this issue will be fixed.

Thank you all who supported.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about how do you "clear" cookies, if you use this box of the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager):

[image]

then it removes **all cookies** on each new iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (other loop generation options like [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) will not trigger clearing of cookies)

Also if your Load Balancer has more that one IP address you might want to add the [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) to your Test Plan in order to avoid DNS requests caching on JVM or OS side.

Comment: So it does not clear the cookies per request right. Acctually I want the session cookie to be avilable without being cleared. So it means it's happening now. Then I wonder what is the issue. Is there a special  way to handel jmeter when we are generating requests for elastic serrver setup with ssticky sessions enabled ?. ( max 10 EC2 instances )